# Graph of model predictions vs observed data when testing a hypothesis

Tags: mixed-model, data-visualization, predictive-models, mean, p-value

I have used mixed models to test a hypothesis and have checked residuals for normality. I was planning to graph the observed data and present it with model outputs (coefficients, p-values). However, graphs with the mean observed data (95% CI), are not in line with the model p-values, but if I graph the model predictions, they are (obviously)! So, my question is, can I present model predictions when testing a hypothesis or do I need to present the observed data? I can send more details if necessary.

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide more details, and also try not to be too concerned with p-values.

Comment: Could you be more specific in terms of the details I need to include please? Thanks.